# Background music HTML - How do I make it play instantaneously when page is loaded?

Tags: html, css

So I've written this piece of music that I would like as background music when browsing my webpage. You should be able to pause it, but I'd like it to play up instantaneously to get some good vibes!

This is my code so far:

```
<audio controls>
<source src="music.mp3" type="audio/ogg">

</audio>
```

I get it to play, but as I said - I want it to start play automatically when you load the page!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unrequested audio on a webpage is a very poor idea, and ideally should never be played without expressed permission of the browsing person. Think about it; you can be anywhere in the world, on any device, and happen to load a website and then ***BAM*** you got  sounds playing at any volume and through any media [such as a DJ set who happens to be browsing while he's playing?]. It's extremely unfriendly from a user point of view. People do not and should not expect it to play unless they expressly wish to play it.

Comment: Side note. I used an iframe with the autoplay tag and set the height and width to 1px so the audio plays and you can't see the video as solution for that situation before. example: <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/acktYyOGG6w?start=29&autoplay=1" width="1" height="1" src="" frameborder="0"  allowfullscreen></iframe>--- I agree with Martin though on that point

Comment: @Martin You're probably right, thank you. Now i know how to do it though, great forum!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the attribute `autoplay`

```
<audio controls autoplay>
<source src="music.mp3" type="audio/ogg">

</audio>
```

**EDIT** And to loop it:

```
<audio controls autoplay loop>
<source src="music.mp3" type="audio/ogg">

</audio>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Also, is it possible to get it to repeat? @Jacob

Comment: Yea, just add "loop" after autoplay. Check my edit in a sec.